# How do I monitor service fabric microservice and sf services memory usage from perfmon

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I want to monitor Service Fabric Process Monitor. I am looking for service fabric services and micro service process monitor like CPU and Memory usage of specific process. When I open up Task Manager I am able to see the CPU and Memory usage but How do I see this in perfmon.

[image]

I have tried looking at Process\PrivateBytes and .net CLR Memory\Total committed bytes but they do not seem the same as what I see in Task Manager.

Which perfmon metrics should I be looking for

Comment: Have you looked at the doc we have for SF performance monitoring? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-generation-perf

Comment: yes but what I need is CPU and memory utilization of specific processes.

Comment: What exactly is the end goal and reason you are looking to do this? I can take a look at what we have but would be good to better understand the what and the why of this scenario

Comment: In our SF we have multiple microservices and sf services (FabricApplicationGateway). Some time some of our microservices consume too much memory or CPU which in turn causes errors. Currently we have to login into the VMs to identify which microservices(*.exe) is consuming most of the resoruces. It would be nice to see this in Log Analytics or Insights

Comment: Thanks for those details. I am working with our SF team offline to see what they can suggest. Will update when I hear back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with the Service Fabric Product Team on this question they have confirmed **% Processor time** is the counter you will want to use. It is available to collect in log analytics and will show which processes of yours are consuming the node’s resources.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-oms-setup

Comment: How did you see it per process though?  I only can see _Total?

Comment: Figured it out  in the Log Analytics > "Advanced Settings" > "Windows Performance Counters" > you can search for counters - so added "Process(*)\% Processor Time "